# Unconfirmed bitcoins deposit from online casion. they paid a fee of 1.82 on a 4k withdrawal.. what do I do?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, cryptography

I made a bitcoin withdrawal from a online casino of $4000. They sent me the payment but it won't confirm. I see they payed a fee of $1.82 so I'm sure thats why it hasnt confirmed yet but Its been a week now and I really need that money. Cash app say they can't do anything and the casino says they can't do anything once the bitcoin leave my casino account. What can I do?